# Parse.com - Cannot add additional fields to User

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Just getting started with Parse.com and following their [JavaScript ToDo app tutorial](https://www.parse.com/tutorials/todo-app-with-javascript) and having some issues.

Basically it will work perfectly and post to the Parse database when I just have the Username and Password but if I try to add any additional fields like email or phone, it won't send it to the database. I have already defined both email and phone fields in my Parse database.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

My html for my form:

```
<script type="text/template" id="login-template">
  <header id="header"></header>
   <form class="signup-form">
      <h2>Sign Up</h2>
      <div class="error" style="display:none"></div>
      <input type="text" id="signup-username" placeholder="Username" />
      <input type="password" id="signup-password" placeholder="Create a Password" />
      <input type="email" id="signup-email" placeholder="Email" />
       <input type="text" id="signup-phone" placeholder="Phone" />
      <button>Sign Up</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</script>
```

My JS:

```
var LogInView = Parse.View.extend({
events: {
  "submit form.signup-form": "signUp"
},

el: ".content",

initialize: function() {
  _.bindAll(this, "signUp");
  this.render();
},

signUp: function(e) {
  var self = this;
  var username = this.$("#signup-username").val();
  var password = this.$("#signup-password").val();
  var email = this.$("#signup-email").val();
  var phone = this.$("#signup-phone").val();

  Parse.User.signUp(username, password, email, phone, { ACL: new Parse.ACL() }, {
    success: function(user) {
      new ManageTodosView();
      self.undelegateEvents();
      delete self;
    },

    error: function(user, error) {
      self.$(".signup-form .error").html(error.message).show();
      self.$(".signup-form button").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
  });

  this.$(".signup-form button").attr("disabled", "disabled");

  return false;
},

render: function() {
  this.$el.html(_.template($("#login-template").html()));
  this.delegateEvents();
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following syntax, like specified in the javascript docs (https://parse.com/docs/js_guide):

```
var user = new Parse.User();
user.set("username",username);
user.set("password",password);
user.set("email",email);
user.set("phone",phone);

user.signUp(null,{
    success:function(user){...},
    error:function(user,error){...}
});
```

You can add any fields you want with the set method.

Comment: How do I integrate that with my form though?

Comment: I just copied my snippet and replaced your Parse.User.signUp line. http://jsfiddle.net/31x9un9m/

Answer (score 0):

I had to change `<!--<button>Submit</button>--> to <!--<input type="submit"></input>-->` to get this to work but then it did. Thanks.